# Need JS to keep the hover link active

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu and i need help getting the hover link to stay active when i hover over it so it blends with the dropdown.

I have put the code on JSF

http://jsfiddle.net/JmR87/2/

Thanks

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for such tasks. See http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/ for a bunch of nice examples, getting this done in pure CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by changing this:

```
#nav-container li a:hover span {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTqNy.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

to this:

```
#nav-container li:hover span {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTqNy.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #000
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/JmR87/5/

Comment: That's right, but you also need to set a `hover` class on those parent `li`s via javascript in order for the hovering to work in IE.

Comment: @Michael Rose: That's only the case for IE6. If he does happen to care about IE6 support (becoming less and less important: [http://ie6countdown.com/](http://ie6countdown.com/)) he can use [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html?sharedBy=Urlsave.net).

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot worked great. I think i need to target for IE aswell though as @MichaelRose says.

Comment: @tom: It works perfectly in IE7 and IE8 and IE9. Are you sure you need *IE6* support?

Comment: I am using a javascript iefix and hover does work ie6. thanks.

Comment: @thirty: Just as a side note ;) I would want to support it either :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the element you are hovering over in the hover function and then remove it when you exit. The class should have the same style has the hover style:

```
$(function () {
  $('.dropdown, .dropdown2, .dropdown3').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().eq(0).hover(function () {
      $('.dropdown, .dropdown2, .dropdown3:eq(0)', this).show();
      $(this).addClass("hoverstyle");
    }, function () {
      $('.dropdown, .dropdown2, .dropdown3:eq(0)', this).hide();
      $(this).removeClass("hoverstyle");
    });
  });
});
```

Then define `.hoverstyle`.

Comment: Thanks @Keltex, Doesnt appear to work even after i define that selector. I have just used :hover instead, seems to work well on ie